# formatDate() gives correct date -1 day (Google Apps Script)

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets, dst

I'm using a Google Spreadsheet to log some things on a day-to-day basis. To make it user-friendly to my colleagues I've made the spreadsheet as "interface-ish" as possible, basically it resembles a form.

This "form" has a submit button that saves the sheet and creates a new sheet (copy of template).

The problem is that the sheet that is saved should be saved with the date from a cell. **BUT it saves with the date one day before the actual date... (!)** I'm going nuts trying to figure out why.

Here's the code from the Google Apps Script I'm calling when the submit button is pressed:

```
function renameSheet() {
var ShootName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet( ).getRange("G8").getValue();
var DateName1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet( ).getRange("A8").getValue();
var newdate = new Date(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet( ).getRange("A8").getValue());
var Datename2 = Utilities.formatDate(newdate, "PST", "yyyy-MM-dd");
var NewName = Datename2 + " - " + ShootName;
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().renameActiveSheet(NewName);
var oldSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
// create a duplicate of the template sheet
ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Original0"));
var newSheet = ss.duplicateActiveSheet();
newSheet.activate();
ss.moveActiveSheet(1);
newSheet.setName("NewLog");

}
```

If cell A8 has the value "12.25.16" - the sheet will be named "12.24.16".

If anyone has a proper or even a dirty quickfix to this, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are hardcoding the timezone in this line :

```
var Datename2 = Utilities.formatDate(newdate, "PST", "yyyy-MM-dd");
```

but this does not take into account the daylight saving and date only values in spreadsheets are always at 00:00:00 hours so one hour shift can change the date...

Replace with an automated value like this :

```
var Datename2 = Utilities.formatDate(newdate, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: we can't use the function getDay() on Datename2. Maybe it is converted into a string. Is there any workaround for it so that we can use getDay() method?
Thank you

Comment: the purpose of this function is actually to get a formatted string... to get access to date method simply use new Date() to create a date object.